# How to get mail after filling contact form using Django

Tags: django, django-views

If the user fills the contact form and submits it, how can the details filled in the contact form be mailed to the admin using this mail?

Am I storing the contact details in database but they should come through mail

Please help thanks

Comment: Can you share the view and the form you are using?

Answer (score 0):

> Am I storing the contact details in database

Yes, you should store it in database then send follow-up mail to user if you wish.

> but they should come through mail

you can't received filled contact form from email user provided.
but you can send mail to your admin email when user fill a new contact form